# Galaxy Note 2 stuck at Samsung logo

Tags: rooting, boot-loop

I have a Galaxy note 2.
My phone is stuck at Samsung logo and restarts every 2 seconds.
I've also recorded my problem [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4h3wx0HHCEE)
I was trying to install a Custom ROM while this occurred, Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. First, you should flash your device back to the official software. [This site](http://www.sammobile.com/firmwares/)
   was useful for me.
2. Once you have returned the device to the original software, attempt to flash the alternate ROM again.

If you installed the latest ROM, the problem will likely be reported soon on the site you obtained the ROM from.

Comment: Really , thank you for replay ! I will doing it and back